# Little Help here with Redux and ReactHooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I have created image gallery... where user can click on page one and page two. when a user clicks on any image on any pages, modal will appear with  that corresponding image along with Title and Description with Submit Button to edit the value and submit..

What i need ?

i need this edit and submit functionality to be implemented using redux... when a user click on page 1 there should be edit function, but same user clicks on page 2, he can click any image and edit title and desc, after submitting the updated value.. that value should be reflected on page one as well as page two

pls refer https://codesandbox.io/s/github/logeshhy/Advanced-React-Hooks-Gallery

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where is your redux file ??

Comment: have to implement redux concept, which i dont know how... thats why seeking help here

Comment: I think simple google can help you :)

Comment: I tried.. getting stuck.. and i am in bit of urgency thats the reason i am asking here without redux code

Comment: If you put the redux part and your stuck , so we can help for the missing or fixing line of code. It's like your asking complete redux functionality for your code. I don't think its little help :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in this branch.
1: Created a store ( with 1 reducer "galaryReducer.js) and provide the store to your main App component in index.js.)
2:  on TileBarGridList I connect with redux to fetch store data.

https://github.com/logeshhy/Advanced-React-Hooks-Gallery/tree/feature/incorporate-redux?files=1